# Python 2.7 sockets: Packed data from struct gets sent to server but server gets stuck on recieve?

Tags: python, sockets, struct

So I'm trying to port 2 scripts I made in 3.5 that lets you send commands from the server to the client and make the client do certain things . One of those certain things are screenshots. What I did in Python 3 was use int.from/to_bytes to pack the length of the file into four bytes with int.to_bytes and sent it over, then the server would use int.from_bytes to unpack to get the filesize and from there loop over to receive the image until there was no data. However, since int.from/to_bytes isn't a thing in 2.7, I tried to use struct instead. My client sent back the struct data fine, but when the server received the data, it just hanged while trying to unpack the struct. Here is (some of) my code (server side):

```
import socket
import struct

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = ''
port = 9999
serversocket.bind((host, port))
serversocket.listen(5)
clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()

print 'Connected to: '+addr[0]

while True:
    m = raw_input("Command > ")
    clientsocket.send(m)
    if m == "exit":
        break
    elif m.split()[0] == 'scrn':
        print "I got here x1"
        xx = clientsocket.recv(4)
        print xx
        remaining = struct.unpack(">I", xx)[0]
        print "I got here x2"
        d = open(m.split()[1]+'.jpg', "wb")
        print "I got here x3"
        while remaining:
            print "I got here x4"
            rbuf = clientsocket.recv(min(remaining, 4096))
            print "I got here x5"
            remaining -= len(rbuf)
            print "I got here x6"
            d.write(rbuf)
            print "I got here x7"
        d.close()
        print "Recieved"

clientsocket.close()
```

As you can see I put several markers in place to test where it gets stuck, and it only prints "I got here x1". I've tried this both on a RPi 3 (testing locally) and tried on a Windows PC.

Also, the client code:

```
import socket
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = 'server ip here'

port = 9999

s.connect((host, port))

while True:   
    msg = s.recv(2048)
    if len(msg) > 0:
        if msg.split()[0] == "scrn":
            #on RPi
            #saveeditorpath = '/home/pi/C'
            saveeditorpath = 'C:\\Users\\*USER HERE*\\Pictures\\'
            #I've tried the ImageGrab from PIL and I tried using pyscreenshot
            img = ImageGrab.grab()
            saveas=os.path.join(saveeditorpath, msg.split()[1]+".jpg")
            img.save(saveas)
            try:
                r = open(os.path.join(saveeditorpath, msg.split()[1]+".jpg"), 'rb')
                data = r.read()
                data_length = len(data)
                r.close()
                s.send(struct.pack(">I", data_length))
                s.send(data)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
        else:
            break
    else:
        pass

s.close()
```

So my question is, why isn't the server unpacking the data I send it and is there any way I can fix this?

EDIT: Seems like I can't even print out the data so new question: Why does the server get stuck recieving the data and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you sure it's not hanging here: `xx = clientsocket.recv(4)` ? can you print the value `xx` you recieved?

Comment: When I interrupt the script with Ctrl+C, it tells me where the code was stuck on and it showed the struct.unpack() line

Comment: right! but still could you print `xx`?

Comment: Oh wow, seems like I can't. So now new question I guess: Why won't it recieve the data?

Comment: That's a tad more complicated without a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Can you cut down your client & server to 2 small scripts that anyone at SO could run from home?

Comment: Alright, I added code anyone could run

Comment: hmmm you have to install image and pyscreenshot packages first. I ran that on my python 3.4 install and it recieved 0 bytes so I could not unpack xx. I'm not that good at sockets, but can you send and receive using the same port? I doubt it.

Comment: I can definitely send and recieve from the same port in Python 3.5... the screenshot function works flawlessly.

Comment: OK, I'll try further.